# Ã± character in in put file being interpreted as ñ in C# console app

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I've seen questions where the two characters are the same, but noting that relates to this specific question so here goes.

I'm running a C# console app that reads an input file that is variable length records. Each record is variable length fields. I've got everything working in terms of parsing out each individual field within each record, not a problem. Except that today I cam across the Ã± character in the input file. Now I know this translates to ñ, so I'm ok with it. However, because I the input file sees Ã± as 2 characters, the record length changes in the C# app because the app is interpreting those 2 characters as a single ñ. This is causing my record length to change from 154 characters to 153, and then during the parsing, messing up the individual fields.

I'm ok with the ñ character getting stored in my DB. But my question is this.

Prior to parsing the fields out of the record, how can I go about easily (with checking every single character) detecting that the ñ exists and trigger it to change the parsing logic? Should I simply do a IndexOf on the character and code it that way? I would think that would add a bit of overhead of I had to put that logic on every single field, although it seems like the easiest way. I would think there's a better way to handle it overall but I've not encountered this before. Most of the posts I have found are more for handling the ñ character in text as opposed to text being converted (properly) from Ã± to ñ

Ideas?

the streamreader open I am using is as follows:

System.IO.StreamReader concatenatedFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\Testing\test.txt",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

The record length changes from 154 characters on the input to 153 interpreted characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the StreamReader you use to read your input file to UTF-8 encoding. I don't believe for a second the original input was meant to be Ã±, so why do you care how many bytes the original input was -  you care about character length, right?

Refer to this article to understand what's what in text encoding: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html .

Comment: I changed the streamreader to this:System.IO.StreamReader concatenatedFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\Testing\\test.txt",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); and got the same result, the record length was not 154 characters, it was 153 characters.

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, edit the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You must always read a text file in the encoding it was written. Of course, sometimes you don't which encoding that was...

Thing of the input file as a stream of bytes. Most are 1-byte-1-ASCII-character, but there are 2 bytes (probably) that can be interpreted differently depending on encoding:

- UTF8 - 1 character, `ñ`
- (some other encoding) - 2 characters, `Ã±`
  Since you say "the input file sees Ã± as 2 characters", this would probably be the encoding intended by whoever produces the file.

So, you should find out which encoding was originally meant, and use that - it's probably some ANSI encoding. You could try `System.Text.Encoding.Default`, but beware that this changes on different machines, so your code will now depend on the machine's default encoding.